# Creating Instance of Nested model inside parent controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I would like to know if it is possible to create an instance of a nested model inside the parents controller.

Let me explain. I have a model called Museum and another model called Museumimage. Museumimage has only one field which is an *attachment*, managed by the *Paperclip* gem. I have created a separate model for this because there can be as many images as desired linked to the Museum model. I thought this would be better than creating, lets say, 20 attachment fields for the Museum model... Most of it being empty..

Then in the NEW view, I have a form allowing to both adding the information for the Museum instance and somes file fields too.

Here is my view important bits :

```
<%= form_for :museum, url: museums_path do |f| %>
<p>
  <%= f.label :name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>    </p>
....
<%= f.file_field :image %><br>
```

(some params such as :name belongs to the Museum model, and :image to the second nested model Museumimage)

I did a pretty straightforward controller, with the CREATE important bits being :

```
@museum = Museum.new(museum_params)
@museum.save
@image = @museum.museumimages.create(image_params)
redirect_to @museum
```

(for one image at the moment)

Though I get error :
**ActionController::ParameterMissing in MuseumsController#create**

This is my first attempt at Paperclip as well.

My questions :

- Is it possible to create an instance on a nested model inside parents
  controller ?
- if this is possible I guess my code has flaws.    Intuitively I think
  my form helper should make a reference to the    nested model
  :museumimage too ?

**EDIT** **EDIT** **EDIT**

I have found a beginning of a solution with the form helpers FIELDS_FOR.

```
<%= f.fields_for :museumimages do |museumimages_fields| %>
  Image: <%= museumimages_fields.file_field :image %>
    <% end  %>
```

But I still get the error message **param is missing or the value is empty: museumimages**

```
app/controllers/museums_controller.rb:191:in `image_params'
app/controllers/museums_controller.rb:129:in `create'

"museumimages"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x475bca8@tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/Maxence/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20160118-8768-obyvra.JPG>,
@original_filename="DSC07825.JPG",
@content_type="image/jpeg",
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"museum[museumimages][image]\"; filename=\"DSC07825.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}},
```

I think my controller bits are not correct.

```
Def Create 
...
@image = @museum.museumimages.new(image_params)
@image.save
end

def image_params
params.require(:museumimages).permit(:image)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look to [accept nested attributes method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), this way the model will allow the instance to be saved, then in the method `image_params` you will need to add an extra param in array form, in this case params.require(:museum).permit(:name, museumimages: [:image])

and that should do the trick

Comment: I do have accepts_nested_attributes_for :museumimages in my parent model. I think I will build the child controller and make sure Paperclip is properly deployed, and come back to it later ..(I am still pretty confused with the whitelisting, attr_access, form helpers ... may see clearer later ..)